# can I register 2 or multiple events for the same socket descriptor on epoll?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, epoll

for the same socket, I want to register two events: one is EPOLLIN and another is EPOLLOUT|EPOLLET.

so for input, I want it to be level trigger and for output I want it to be edge trigger.

```
            ev.data.fd=fd;
            ev.events=EPOLLIN;
            epoll_ctl(epfd,EPOLL_CTL_ADD,fd,&ev);
            ev.events=EPOLLOUT|EPOLLET;
            epoll_ctl(epfd,EPOLL_CTL_ADD,fd,&ev);
```

is it possible or not? are there any problems? thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's from [`epoll(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) **Questions and answers** section:

> **`Q1`**  What happens if you register the same file descriptor on an `epoll` instance twice?
>
> **`A1`**  You will probably get `EEXIST`. However, it is possible to add a duplicate (`dup(2)`, `dup2(2)`, `fcntl(2)` `F_DUPFD`) descriptor to the same `epoll instance`. This can be a useful technique for filtering events, if the duplicate file descriptors are registered with different *`events`* masks.